# RecyclerView taking longer to open in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am building an conversation application in java , based on room database. And using paging 3 lib. now the requirment is while user open any thread he should scrolled to the bottom means the last to item. But the issues are 1. its taking a long time to open the thread. i want a smooth navigation like whatsapp/ telegram.
2. WHILE any data set changed in db its not following the flow.
please see the video [loading time](https://attachment.artixdevelopment.site/loading_time.mp4)  is the main issue.

please help me to solve .

I am using live data like this

in fragment

```
  groups_chat_viewModel.getMessageBy_paging(id).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), group_chats -> {
            
                adapter.submitData(getLifecycle(),group_chats);
        
        });
```

And in repository

```
            LiveData<PagingData<Group_Chat>> all_chat_paged = null;
          /* all_chat_paged = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(
                   Chat_dao.getMessageBy_paging(strings[0]),20
                    ).build();
            return all_chat_paged;*/


            Pager<Integer, Group_Chat> pager = new Pager(
                    // Create new paging config
                    new PagingConfig(30, //  Count of items in one page
                            90, //  Number of items to prefetch
                            false, // Enable placeholders for data which is not yet loaded
                            30, // initialLoadSize - Count of items to be loaded initially
                            PagingConfig.MAX_SIZE_UNBOUNDED),// maxSize - Count of total items to be shown in recyclerview
                    () -> Chat_dao.getMessageBy_paging(strings[0]));

            CoroutineScope coroutineScope = ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(groups_chat_viewModel);
            all_chat_paged = PagingLiveData.cachedIn(PagingLiveData.getLiveData(pager), coroutineScope);
            return all_chat_paged;
```